# How can I set up Eclipse workspace mechanic to share settings?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workspace

How do I configure this tool?

I already have my preferences set up in my Eclipse environment, the bottom icon shows that workspace mechanic is ok. But when I open a workspace or create a new workspace nothing happens, none of the preferences are there.

How do I set up workspace mechanic, and how do I tell a workspace to use the settings of another workspace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, workspace mechanic shares no settings between workspaces. To share settings, they have to be told the tool manually.

This can be done two ways: the mechanic allows a [preference change recording on the GUI](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/wiki/PreferenceRecorder) , or you can [manually create configurations](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/wiki/PreferenceExamples).

Basically, both ways result in `.epf` files in your `«home folder»/.eclipse/mechanic` directory. All installed workspace mechanic instances will look at these folders.

Comment: Ok, now I got the start recording stuff to list a couple of things, I had tried that before with no success, but this time I changed a hotkey before stopping it. So I should save the .epf file in .eclipse/mechanic. there is already a editor_config.epf there, what happens if you have two .epf files in that folder? Is it possible to  set up so workspaces use different settings ( two sets of settings for example ). Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually have to record every setting ? The fonts and syntax coloring is not being picked up by other project. When I start record, edit a color, stop, it gets picked up, but if I change the setting, start record, stop record it doesnt. It would really suck if you have to be in recording mode all the time, especially if that is not on by default. How can I get those settings that happened outside of recording mode to be picked up?

Comment: Ok, I just exported by using the normal export preferences, replaced all in .eclipse/mechanic so I only have one file, and now it is working. It should be explained alot easier.. Thanks for your help, let me know if I missed something!

Comment: I think, it works basically this way. I don't know the shortcomings in detail, but for me it was similarly problematic.